# Как настроить визуальный редактор CKEDITOR/TinyMCE в область textarea?

Tags: jquery, javascript, tinymce, ckeditor, редактор

Скачал CKEDITOR 4.4.7, подключил в head скрипт ckeditor.js.

После тега `<textarea id="editor1"></textarea>` вставил, как и написано:

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

Визуальный редактор подключился и отобразился, однако изменения (цвета, толщины шрифты и т.д.) не сохраняются, сохраняется только текст.

Как можно это исправить?

---

Всё, разобрался, оказывается перед занесением в БД забыл убрать обработку данных функцией strip_tags, которая убирает тэги.

Comment: не сохраняются цвета, толщины шрифты после перезагрузки страницы? или после выделения и нажатия, например, на **B** ??

Comment: Не сохраняются именно после перезагрузки (я думал еще, что проблемы с запросом к базе данных), но сам текст сохраняется.

Comment: Разобрался, оказывается, забыл убрать функцию strip_tags перед внесением в БД.